# How accessibility works for rating component?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, rating

I am creating a rating component , and wanted to add accessibility feature to it. What all aria-attributes has to be added? What are the tab navigation required? 
i.e how it should behave on right/left arrow click or click on other keys?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no unique definitive answer to this question. You may design your component rather differently, depending on the exact desired behavior.

Is your rating component read only ? Can the user rate only once for all or change his mind at any time ?
When the user sets or changes a rating, is it taken into account immediately or does he have to click an OK/save button ?
Are three of the few questions that may change things.

For example, probably the simplest: 
you may view your component as a serie of radio buttons labelled 1, 2, 3, ... 10.
If you use true radio buttons `<input type="radio"/>` with accompagning labels, you have very little to do to make your component accessible.

A bit harder, you may see your component as being a slider. IN this case it's going to be  more difficult because you will probably need to use some ARIA.
Refer to W3C authoring practice for implementing it correctly.

This was for a component allowing input. Now if your component is read only or become read only once the user has given a rating, remember that, after all, a rating is just a ratio between two numbers, the rate obtained and the maximum possible rate.

How fancy you present the result to the normal user has finally little importance as long as you give the two numbers in text somewhere, e.g. "4/5" or "4 starts out of 5" in a place and in a form where it can be read as is. The rest is pure optional decoration.

However, if you really don't want to give the numbers in clear somewhere, you are going to fail. For example, color blind won't see if it's green or red, screen readers users won't figure out the size or number of bars, etc.
I can well understand the willing to hide exact numbers for many reasons, but it's a bad idea for accessibility.